# Why is IE8 rendering a page with JavaScript unusable while FF is doing fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer, firefox

**LINK TO THE PAGE NO LONGER ACTIVE, THANKS FOR VISITING, Rene**

Hi,

I have a page [here](http://www.google.com) and I can't understand why is IE8 rendering this page so slowly.
Originally I thought it was the scrolling text at the top but it's not as I commented it out with no progress. So then I profiled with developer tools for IE8 and it shows a lot of  anonymous functions running which I suspect come from jquery (which is not loaded by me directly) but the developer tools cannot show me the source code for those functions. So I can't pin down the problem on what are those phantom functions running from or why as I have no experience with jquery. I noticed that those functions do not run in FF when I profiled it with FireBug so maybe something is running for IE but not for FF ? I am a bit lost.

Any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much,
Rene

Comment: Hmmm...Which web browser is the sick one?

Comment: @LordCover: IE8, it shows me 100% usage of the CPU

Comment: The best way to solve this problem is to continously comment out snippets of the web page until you encounter the specific line/statement that breaks it.

Comment: Please put some code here (the relevant bits, as far as you can tell), even though you have the link, because the document may change as you work on it and doing so makes it easier on those trying to answer the question. It's also better for archival purposes. Cheers.

Comment: Use the [non-minimized version of jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js) if you need to see what's happening within it, should do for non-production code anyway for precisely this reason.

Comment: @meder @D_N @Orbling: thank you for your suggestions I'll try them. I currently don't know what is the relevant code though but if I find  something I'll post

Comment: Do try to keep in mind that IE *is* many many times slower at JS than FireFox, and compared to Chrome, which compiles to native, it is a snail.

Comment: maybe try dynatrace for IE debugging.. pretty damn good ..http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/

Comment: Thanks everyone! I appreciate your help a lot. I'm taking the site down, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to see the process jumping between 79MB and 65MB off and on. It may be an issue of memory not being freed up or perhaps an inefficient background operation that is hanging everything up.

I would go with meder5's advice. I would comment any and all unnecessary code and start with the bare minimum and track performance till you find the bottleneck as you add pieces back in.

Comment: @rene GL, sometimes you get lucky and find it right away ... and sometimes you will gut everything out lol

Answer (score 1):

Hi I also tested in Chrome 8. Frankly, the page is neither fast in IE nor FF nor Chrome. But its relatively faster in FF and Chrome much than IE. I suppose it has something to do with the different mechanisms of FF/Chrome and IE use handling contents.

By the way, I appreciate that you guys can do very nice animation with javascript&jquery,

Comment: thanks for testing. Yeah the page is slow in all broswers. I think I'll take it down tomorrow.